# Android Architecture Components: Gradle sync error for dependency version

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to add ViewModel and LiveData to a Kotlin app. I have the following dependencies added to my module's `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
```

I'm given the following error:

> Android dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Removing the first line (`extensions`) fixes the issue, indicating that the error is coming from there, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: add ` implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1"` to your dependencies

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Dependency Resolution Force to use a version https://gist.github.com/cr7pt0gr4ph7/6cd6339eabc2056bc3e7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently `support-v4` was causing the conflict. In the case of this question, the Gradle dependency task wasn't working correctly, but for anyone else who runs into this issue:

`./gradlew :app:dependencies` will show the sub-dependencies used by your dependencies. Search the output of this command (changing `app` for your module name) for the dependency causing the conflict.

Comment: This was the case for me as well, setting the resolutionStrategy above solved the problem.

Answer (score 48):

As @RedBassett mentions Support libraries depends on this lightweight import (runtime library) as explained at [android developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components).

This is, android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0 is spreading up in the dependency tree as a result of an internal api (transitive) import so in my case I only had to include extensions library as "api" instead of "implementation" so that it will override its version to the highest (1.1.1).

In conclusion, change

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

to

```
api "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

Comment: lifesaver, not sure why this isn't documented some place

Comment: Same here (another lifesaver).

Comment: 'api' is less efficient than 'implementation' in terms of build time after changes

Answer (score 24):

In your main `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    ...

    configurations {
        all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This will enforce version `1.1.1`

Comment: This worked for me. I was unable to figure out where the lower dependency was, as it was most Lilley in an older library.

Answer (score 1):

@RedBassett is right. However I was still having some problem excluding `android.arch.lifecycle` related sub dependencies.

In my case the conflict was caused in `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`.

This is how my gradle dependency looks like after excluding it.

```
implementation ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'android.arch.lifecycle'
}


api "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

Also, you will have to add this exclude in every imported module.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for all dependencies with `./gradlew :app:dependencies` as @RedBassett mentioned. I noticed the incompatible version of `android.arch.core:runtime` that Gradle was complaining about was stemming from my version of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`, so I just updated that version to the latest and everything worked.